# What should be done with a question asked on EL&U which is successively asked from the same user on ELL?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I am used to *Stack Overflow*, where when somebody asks the same question on *Stack Overflow*, and *Drupal Answers*, I flag the question for moderation attention (using "other" as flagging reason), explaining the same user asked the same question on *Drupal Answers*, and giving a link to the question on that site. What the moderators do in these cases is closing the question on *Stack Overflow*, and eventually comment on the question being cross-posted; sometimes, the moderators add a note for the OP about not cross-posting questions that are on-topic on more than one site.

Notice that in the case I flag the questions, the questions are carbon copies, not questions that are rephrased to ask slightly different, or follow-up questions; they are not even questions that are tailored for the site where they are asked.

Should I do the same for questions that are asked on EL&U, and then are asked on ELL when somebody suggest the other site for the question?

Comment: What sorts of moderator attention do your flags trigger? What do they do about this?

Comment: See the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Given that ELL is still only in Beta mode, we probably don't particularly *want* mods to take too many decisions about questions posed on both sites. We're supposed to be *collectively* defining the scope of ELL, not expecting the mods to present us with a *fait accompli*.

Therefore I think the best thing to do is post a *comment* against the question (on either or both sites) linking to the duplicate on the other site. That way, many more users (those with the rep to closevote) can directly affect what happens.

Even those without that level of privilege can influence the decision - they'll see what's happened, they can up/downvote on either/both sites, and they can participate in the debate via comments.

Don't burden the mods with flags that need attention, when there isn't yet an established procedure for determining exactly what to do in any given case. Let the community/ies decide case-by-case.

Comment: I am not sure the fact ELL is still in public beta phase is relevant for EL&U. Since I don't see much questions cross-posted, it cannot be "burdening the mods."

Comment: @kiamlaluno: There's currently no "migrate to the other site" closevote option in either direction, and my understanding is TPTB aren't keen to *ever* implement it. But *if* you flag for a mod to consider migrating (which is after all what your question here seems to be seeking opinions about), you're effectively asking *mods* to make the decision as to which site any given question should go on. I just don't think we should pre-empt the possibility of such decisions being made by "community consensus", at least while ELL is in the process of defining itself.

Comment: Why would you migrate a question that is asked on EL&U and ELL? I am not speaking of migrating in my question, nor did I say that when a user asks the same question on both Stack Overflow and Drupal Answers, the question is migrated.

Comment: @@kiamlaluno: As so often happens with me and thee, we seem to be just going round in circles. Okay, I'm using "migrate" loosely here - the point is you're concerned about *the same question* being asked on both sites, which by implication means you think it should only be on *one* site. And by further implication, there's a decision to be made as to *which* site it should survive on.

Comment: There is no "loose" meaning for _migrate_ on Stack Exchange sites. _We_ are going in circles because you are not answering to what being asked. Clearly, if I am asking the question on the meta for EL&U, I am talking of questions that are better suits for ELL. EL&U moderators cannot do anything for questions asked on EL&U and ELL, and which should be asked on EL&U, if not casting a flag on ELL.